# sql left join error using Month(date) in select statment

Tags: mysql, sql

**This code is working:**

```
select Date1,  Date2
from 
    (SELECT Date1 FROM Table1 GROUP BY Date1) t1
left join
    (SELECT Date2 FROM Table2 GROUP BY Date2) t2
on
    t1.Date1 = t2.Date2
```

**But I need to use it extracting Month(...) so when I change code like this I've getting an error:**

> Unknown column 'Date1' in 'field list'

```
select Date1,  Date2
from 
    (SELECT Month(Date1) FROM Table1 GROUP BY Date1) t1
left join
    (SELECT Month(Date2) FROM Table2 GROUP BY Date2) t2
on
    t1.Date1 = t2.Date2
```

Actually the code is bigger and only this part of code does not let me to proceed..

Answer (score 1):

**Alias name** for `month` is missing in the inner select query

```
select Date1,  Date2
from 
    (SELECT Month(Date1) as date1 --Alias missing Here
     FROM Table1 
     GROUP BY Date1) t1
left join
    (SELECT Month(Date2) as date2 --Alias missing here
     FROM Table2 
     GROUP BY Date2) t2
on
    t1.Date1 = t2.Date2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Engine throws an error because it couldn't find this name entity in your subquery.
As mentioned by this user you need to provide aliases in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The alias name is missing while using the Month():

```
select Date1,  Date2
from 
    (SELECT Month(Date1) month1 FROM Table1 GROUP BY Date1) t1
left join
    (SELECT Month(Date2) month2 FROM Table2 GROUP BY Date2) t2
on
    t1.Date1 = t2.Date2
```